# WebStorm is not refreshing files when using gulp.watch

Tags: gulp, webstorm, gulp-watch

I am using WebStorm 9, I have a very basic gulp file script setup to copy 1 file from directory `src` to directory `build`.

I have found that when changing the content of `index.html` file in the `src` directory gulp copies the file fine to the `build` directory... but WebStorm does not show that unless I use `File | Synchronize`.

Why is this? How can I get WebStorm to show the change without using `File | Synchronize`?

My gulp file consists of the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')

gulp.task('copyme', function(){
    return gulp.src('./src/index.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/index.html'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./src/index.html', ['copyme']);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[IDEA-136705](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136705) is closed as fixed, fix should become available in WebStorm 10